# Visual C# RDLC Report Dynamic Text Coloring Based on Background Values

Tags: rdlc

I am creating an RDLC report in a program I wrote in C#. It gets data from a MySQL server, and feeds it to the report. Part of this data is a string that stores a hex value for the background of a textbox on the report. I need an expression for the foreground of the textbox to dynamically change the color of the text if the background color is too dark. I do not know the colors coming into the report previously (i.e. a Switch statement based off specific colors would not work)

I was thinking to try to separate the red green and blue values of the string and logically saying:

IF ([red and blue are too low] OR [red and green are too low] OR [blue and green are too low])
THEN 
(set foreground color to white)
ELSE
(set foreground color to black)

the expression for the text color would go look something like:

=IIF(Fields!reportColorCode.Value [condition - this is where I am stuck], "#FFFFFF", "#000000")

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or questions to clarify what I am trying to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what I was trying to do, this is what I came up with, not really efficient but it parses the hex string(ex. "#EDF32A") and looks at the 2nd, 4th, and 6th character and if two of the 2nd, 4th, and 6th characters equal 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 at the same time, then the color is dark enough to change the text to white.

```
=IIF(
    (
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "7"
        ) 
        AND 
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "7"        
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 2, 1) = "7"
        ) 
        AND 
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "7"        
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 6, 1) = "7"        
        ) 
        AND 
        (
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "0" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "1" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "2" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "3" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "4" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "5" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "6" OR
       MID(Fields!reportColorCode.Value, 4, 1) = "7"        
        )
    )
    ,"#FFFFFF", "#000000"
)
```